# Struggling to derive ODE when differentiating equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am currently reading the Theoretical Neuroscience book by Dayan and Abbott. In the chapter on network models, the following equation is presented:

$$I = \sum_{b=1}^{N} w_b \int_{-\infty}^{t} d\tau K(t-\tau) u_b(\tau)$$

where $K(t)=\frac{1}{\tau}\exp{(\frac{-t}{\tau})}$.

In the book, the equation above is differentiated, from which the following ODE is obtained.

$$\tau \frac{dI}{dt}=-I+\sum_{b=1}^{N} w_b u_b$$

However, when differentiating, I arrive at

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{dI}{dt}&=\sum_{b=1}^{N} w_b \int_{-\infty}^{t} d\tau \frac{d}{dt} K(t-\tau) u_b(\tau) \\
\frac{dI}{dt}&= -\frac{1}{\tau}\sum_{b=1}^{N} w_b \int_{-\infty}^{t} d\tau K(t-\tau) u_b(\tau) \\
\tau \frac{dI}{dt}&=-I
\end{split}
\end{equation}

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't differentiate correctly, use the Leibniz rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule because the bounds depend on the variable which you are differentiating with respect to.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Leibniz rule we get,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{dI}{dt}&=\sum_{b=1}^{N} w_b \left(K(t-t)u_b(t)+\int_{-\infty}^{t} d\tau \frac{d}{dt} K(t-\tau) u_b(\tau) \right)\\
\frac{dI}{dt}&= \frac{1}{\tau}\sum_{b=1}^{N} w_b\left(u_b- \int_{-\infty}^{t} d\tau K(t-\tau) u_b(\tau) \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Would this still derivation still apply if $u_b(\tau)=\sum_{i}\sigma(\tau-t_i)$ where $\sigma$ is the dirac delta function?

Comment: In a distributional sense, yeah.

Comment: What happens though if you numerically discretise the ODE? How would you then interpret the dirac delta function (without being within an integral)? As far as I understand it's taken to be either 0 or 1, instead of 0 or infinity. Does that sound mathematically sound?

Comment: You can't interpret distributions outside an integral, they are thought of as linear functionals on a space of test functions so the integration is baked into the cake (to make them linear functionals). That being said, I have seen people do what you suggested, and this is because the unit impulse (what you described) is the discrete analog of the dirac delta.